# Segmentation Fault from printing a linked list after reading from a file

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, printf

I've almost completed my C program to add, view, save and load patient details. I've completed the add, save and load but can't seem to get the save function implemented correctly.

The program will allow users to add patient details, then save the details into a text file database. Users can then exit from the program, start the program and load the text file database. Finally, users will be able to see the patient details in the program.

In my code, I've also added some code to print out the contents after reading the text file, which works, printing out all the patient details onto the terminal. However, after I read from the text file, I try to use the view patient function and get a segmentation fault. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DB_NAME "database"

struct dob
{
int day, month, year;
};
typedef struct dob dob_t;

struct medicine
{
int medicine_id;
char medicine_name[100];
};
typedef struct medicine medicine_t;

struct patient
{
    int patient_id;
    dob_t date_db;
    char patient_name[20];
    medicine_t patient_med;
    struct patient* nextp; 

};
typedef struct patient patient_t;

void print_menu (void);
patient_t* add_patients (patient_t* patient_headp, patient_t* temp, patient_t* patient_currentp, int num_patients);
void view_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp);
void save_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp);
patient_t* read_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp, patient_t* temp);


int main (void){
patient_t* patient_headp = NULL;
patient_t* temp = NULL;
patient_t* patient_currentp = NULL;
int option_picked = 0;
int num_patients = 0;
while(option_picked != 5)
{
    print_menu ();
    scanf("%d", &option_picked);
    if (option_picked == 1){
        patient_headp = add_patients(patient_headp, temp, patient_currentp, num_patients);
    }


    else if (option_picked == 2){
        view_patients (patient_currentp, patient_headp);
    }


    else if (option_picked == 3){
        save_patients (patient_currentp, patient_headp);
    }


    else if (option_picked == 4){
        patient_headp = read_patients (patient_currentp, patient_headp, temp);
    }
}   
return 0;
}

void print_menu (void)
{
printf("\n"
"1. add a patient\n"
"2. display all patients\n"
"3. save the patients to the database file\n"
"4. load the patients from the database file\n"
"5. exit the program\n"
"Enter choice (number between 1-5)>\n");
}

patient_t* add_patients (patient_t* patient_headp, patient_t* temp, patient_t* patient_currentp, int num_patients){
char choice;
do
{
    temp = (patient_t*) malloc(sizeof(patient_t));
    if (temp == NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    }
    printf("Enter Patient ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->patient_id);
    printf("Enter Patient DOB(DD MM YY): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &temp->date_db.day, &temp->date_db.month, 
    &temp->date_db.year);
    printf("Enter Patient Name: ");
    scanf("%s", temp->patient_name);
    printf("Enter Patient Medicine Prescription: ");
    scanf("%s", temp->patient_med.medicine_name);
    printf("Enter Patient Medicine Prescription ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->patient_med.medicine_id);
    temp->nextp = NULL;
    if(patient_headp == NULL){
        patient_headp = temp;
    }
    else{
        patient_currentp = patient_headp;
        while(patient_currentp->nextp != NULL){
            patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
        }
        patient_currentp->nextp = temp;
    }
    printf("Add more patients? (Y/N) ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    num_patients++;
} 
while (choice == 'Y');
return patient_headp;
}


void view_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp){
    /*patient_currentp = (patient_t*) malloc(sizeof(patient_t));
    if (patient_currentp == NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    }
    patient_currentp = patient_headp;
    do{
        printf("%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", patient_currentp->patient_id, 
        patient_currentp->date_db.day, patient_currentp->date_db.month, 
        patient_currentp->date_db.year, patient_currentp->patient_name, 
        patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
        patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_id);
        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
    }while(patient_currentp->nextp != NULL);*/
    printf("%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", patient_headp->patient_id, 
        patient_headp->date_db.day, patient_headp->date_db.month, 
        patient_headp->date_db.year, patient_headp->patient_name, 
        patient_headp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
        patient_headp->patient_med.medicine_id);
}


void save_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp){
    FILE *output = fopen(DB_NAME, "a");
    if (output == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
    }
    patient_currentp = patient_headp;
    do{
        fprintf(output, "%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", patient_currentp->patient_id, 
        patient_currentp->date_db.day, patient_currentp->date_db.month, 
        patient_currentp->date_db.year, patient_currentp->patient_name, 
        patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
        patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_id);

        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
    }while(patient_currentp != NULL);
    fclose(output);
}


patient_t* read_patients (patient_t* patient_currentp, patient_t* patient_headp, patient_t* temp){
    FILE *input = fopen(DB_NAME, "r");
    if (input == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
    }
    do{
        temp = (patient_t*) malloc(sizeof(patient_t));
        if (temp == NULL){
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        }
        while ((fscanf(input, "%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d", 
        &temp->patient_id, &temp->date_db.day, 
        &temp->date_db.month, &temp->date_db.year, 
        temp->patient_name, 
        temp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
        &temp->patient_med.medicine_id)) != EOF)

        printf("%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", temp->patient_id, 
        temp->date_db.day, temp->date_db.month, 
        temp->date_db.year, temp->patient_name, 
        temp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
        temp->patient_med.medicine_id);

        temp->nextp = NULL;
        if(patient_headp == NULL){
            patient_headp = temp;
        }
        else{
            patient_currentp = patient_headp;
            while(patient_currentp->nextp != NULL){
                patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
            }
            patient_currentp->nextp = temp;
        }
    }while(patient_currentp != NULL);
return patient_headp;
}
```

Comment: If you want help debugging your assignment, you should approach your tutors, not this site. I suggest reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ viz "StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story. “Why does subtracting one from zero produce a number that is larger than zero, causing my comparison against zero on line 12 to incorrectly become true?” is a specific question about actual code."

Comment: Hint, what did you just `free` when you `while (choice == 'Y'); free(temp);`.?? Didn't you assign the block of memory pointed to by `temp` to something important??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, however, that doesn't help with my segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm not saying that is the only reason for you SegFault, but when you `temp = (patient_t*) malloc(sizeof(patient_t));` (note: see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)) and then `patient_headp = temp;` or `patient_currentp->nextp = temp;` and then `free (temp);` -- where does `patient_headp` or `patient_currentp->nextp` point?

Comment: Also, your `view_patients` function should work (but should be type `void` as the return is meaningless). Further, there is no need for `patient_t* patient_currentp` as a parameter, just declare `patient_t* patient_currentp = patient_headp;` within the function itself. You also need to either check `patient_headp != NULL` before looping, or change your loop from a `do {...} while (..);` to `while () {...}` so a `NULL` `patient_headp` doesn't SegFault.

Answer (score 1):

The reality of your problem is (1) without input validation there are so many potential sources of error that could lead to *Undefined Behavior* and a Segmentation Fault that it is difficult to pin down (2) any time the address of the list could change in a function (e.g. the first node changes), you need to pass the *address of* `patient_headp` so that the function receives the actual list pointer instead a copy of a pointer holding the list address, and (3) your `read_patients()` is non-functional (for a number of reasons), but fundamentally because setting `patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;` guarantees `while(patient_currentp != NULL);` test false.

There is no reason to pass `patient_currentp` as a parameter. There is no reason to pass `num_patients` in its current form, the parameter is unused, and for it to be useful you would need to pass a pointer to `num_patients` so you could update it within your add and read functions and make the updated counts available back in the calling function.

Before we even look at code, taking user input with `scanf` is wrought with pitfalls for the unwary in the event of a *matching* or *input* failure. To even begin to use `scanf` correctly you must **validate the return** every time. This means handling `EOF`, a *matching* or *input* failure, and handling the valid input case. At minimum, you must check that the anticipated number of conversions took place before making use of the input.

In the event of a *matching failure*, character extraction from the input buffer stops, leaving the offending character unread just waiting to bite you on your next attempt to read. To facilitate recovering from a *matching failure*, it is up to you to removed the offending characters from the input buffer. The normal approach for `stdin` is simply reading with `getchar()` until `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered. A short helper-function makes life easier, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

In addition to the validation issue, you may find it more robust to indicate success/failure in your `add_patients()` function by returning a pointer to the node added (or `NULL` on failure). This is somewhat complicated by your looping within the function to add multiple patients rather than simply calling the function again from the menu. Regardless, returning a pointer to the last node added works equally well.

There is no way possible to step through every issue in your code in the characters allotted for this answer. Instead, I've tidied up your code in a way that addresses each user-input validation, removes unnecessary parameters from your function declarations, and changed the return types for `save_patients()` and `read_patients()` to `int` to provide `1` on successful write or read, `0` otherwise.

(**note** the validation of `fclose` in `save_patients()`. Any time you are **writing** to a file, you should validate `fclose` as it will catch stream errors as well as errors with your last write that may not have been capable of reporting until close)

The code follows your approach, it has just been refined in several places. Look it over:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DB_NAME "database"
#define MAXRX   100         /* if you need constants, #define on (or more) */
#define MAXNM    20         /*  (don't use "magic numbers" in your code )  */

typedef struct {
    int day, month, year;
} dob_t;

typedef struct {
    int medicine_id;
    char medicine_name[MAXRX];
} medicine_t;

typedef struct patient {
    int patient_id;
    dob_t date_db;
    char patient_name[MAXNM];
    medicine_t patient_med;
    struct patient* nextp; 
} patient_t;

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

void print_menu (void);
patient_t *add_patients (patient_t **patient_headp, int *num_patients);
void view_patients (patient_t *patient_headp);
int save_patients (patient_t *patient_headp);
int read_patients (patient_t **patient_headp, int *num_patients);


int main (void) {

    patient_t   *patient_headp = NULL;
    int option_picked = 0,
        num_patients = 0;

    while(option_picked != 5)
    {
        print_menu ();
        if (scanf("%d", &option_picked) != 1) { /* VALIDATE EVERY USER INPUT */
            fputs ("\n  error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        if (option_picked == 1)
            add_patients (&patient_headp, &num_patients);
        else if (option_picked == 2)
            view_patients (patient_headp);
        else if (option_picked == 3)
            save_patients (patient_headp);
        else if (option_picked == 4)
            read_patients (&patient_headp, &num_patients);
    }   
    return 0;
}

void print_menu (void)
{
    printf ("\n"
            "1. add a patient\n"
            "2. display all patients\n"
            "3. save the patients to the database file\n"
            "4. load the patients from the database file\n"
            "5. exit the program\n\n"
            "Enter choice (number between 1-5)> ");
}

patient_t *add_patients (patient_t **patient_headp, int *num_patients)
{
    patient_t   *patient_currentp = *patient_headp,
                *temp = NULL;
    char choice = 0;

    do
    {
        temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);           /* allocate */
        if (temp == NULL){                      /* validate */
            perror ("add_patients-malloc");
            return NULL;
        }
        temp->nextp = NULL;                     /* initialize */

        printf ("Enter Patient ID: ");
        if (scanf ("%d", &temp->patient_id) != 1)
            goto error_add_pt;

        printf ("Enter Patient DOB(DD MM YY): ");
        if (scanf ("%d %d %d", &temp->date_db.day, &temp->date_db.month, 
                            &temp->date_db.year) != 3)
            goto error_add_pt;

        printf ("Enter Patient Name: ");
        if (scanf ("%s", temp->patient_name) != 1)
            goto error_add_pt;

        printf ("Enter Patient Medicine Prescription: ");
        if (scanf ("%s", temp->patient_med.medicine_name) != 1)
            goto error_add_pt;

        printf ("Enter Patient Medicine Prescription ID: ");
        if (scanf ("%d", &temp->patient_med.medicine_id) != 1)
            goto error_add_pt;

        if (*patient_headp == NULL){
            *patient_headp = patient_currentp = temp;
        }
        else {
            while (patient_currentp->nextp != NULL){
                patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
            }
            patient_currentp->nextp = temp;
        }
        (*num_patients)++;

        printf ("Add more patients? (Y/N) ");
        if (scanf (" %c", &choice) < 1) {
            fputs (" user canceled input.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
    } 
    while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');

    return temp;    /* return pointer to most recent node added */

  error_add_pt:;
    fputs ("error: invalid input\n", stderr);
    empty_stdin();
    free (temp);
    return NULL;
}


void view_patients (patient_t *patient_headp)
{
    patient_t *patient_currentp = patient_headp;

    while (patient_currentp != NULL) {
        printf ("%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", patient_currentp->patient_id, 
                patient_currentp->date_db.day, patient_currentp->date_db.month, 
                patient_currentp->date_db.year, patient_currentp->patient_name, 
                patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
                patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_id);

        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
    }   
}


int save_patients (patient_t *patient_headp)
{
    patient_t *patient_currentp = patient_headp;
    FILE *output = fopen(DB_NAME, "a");

    if (output == NULL) {   /* validate file open to append */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", DB_NAME);
        return 0;
    }

    while(patient_currentp != NULL) {

        fprintf (output, "%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", 
                patient_currentp->patient_id, 
                patient_currentp->date_db.day, patient_currentp->date_db.month, 
                patient_currentp->date_db.year, patient_currentp->patient_name, 
                patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_name, 
                patient_currentp->patient_med.medicine_id);

        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
    }

    if (fclose (output) == EOF) {
        fputs ("error: stream error on fclose.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int read_patients (patient_t **patient_headp, int *num_patients)
{
    patient_t   tmp = {0},
                *patient_currentp = *patient_headp;
    FILE *input = fopen(DB_NAME, "r");

    if (input == NULL){ /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", DB_NAME);
        return 0;
    }

    while (patient_currentp && patient_currentp->nextp != NULL)
        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;

    while (fscanf (input, "%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %19s %99s %d", 
                &tmp.patient_id, &tmp.date_db.day, 
                &tmp.date_db.month, 
                &tmp.date_db.year, 
                tmp.patient_name, 
                tmp.patient_med.medicine_name, 
                &tmp.patient_med.medicine_id) == 7) {

        patient_t *node = malloc (sizeof *node);
        if (node == NULL) {
            perror ("read_patients-malloc");
            return 0;
        }
        node->nextp = NULL;

        *node = tmp;

        if (!patient_currentp)
            *patient_headp = patient_currentp = node;
        else {
            patient_currentp->nextp = node;
            patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
        }
        (*num_patients)++;

        printf ("%05d %02d/%02d/%02d %s %s %d\n", node->patient_id, 
                node->date_db.day, node->date_db.month, 
                node->date_db.year, node->patient_name, 
                node->patient_med.medicine_name, 
                node->patient_med.medicine_id);
    }

    fclose (input);

    return 1;
}
```

(**note:** your repeated allocation for `patient_currentp` in `read_patients()` was leaking memory and overwriting the pointer values you had previously assigned to your list. That is why an additional `node` variable is used)

**Example Use/Output - Entering Data**

```
$ ./bin/llpatients

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 1
Enter Patient ID: 10001
Enter Patient DOB(DD MM YY): 1 1 72
Enter Patient Name: Epoch
Enter Patient Medicine Prescription: Clonapin
Enter Patient Medicine Prescription ID: 2001
Add more patients? (Y/N) y
Enter Patient ID: 10002
Enter Patient DOB(DD MM YY): 31 10 72
Enter Patient Name: Halloween
Enter Patient Medicine Prescription: Potion
Enter Patient Medicine Prescription ID: 2002
Add more patients? (Y/N) n

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 2
10001 01/01/72 Epoch Clonapin 2001
10002 31/10/72 Halloween Potion 2002

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 3

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 5
```

**Example Use/Output - Reading From File**

```
$ ./bin/llpatients

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 4
10001 01/01/72 Epoch Clonapin 2001
10002 31/10/72 Halloween Potion 2002

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 2
10001 01/01/72 Epoch Clonapin 2001
10002 31/10/72 Halloween Potion 2002

1. add a patient
2. display all patients
3. save the patients to the database file
4. load the patients from the database file
5. exit the program

Enter choice (number between 1-5)> 5
```

Again, look things over, understand why the changes that were made, were made, and ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: is there any way to contact you personally?

Comment: Well, sure, drankinatty at gmail will do. I'm happy to help further.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, in the main function, after `option_picked == 5` then it's not freed.  probably need something like `    while(patient_headup)
    {
        patient_t *victim = patient_headup;
        patient_headup = patient_headup->nextp;
        free(victim);
    }`

Comment: @jian - you are getting good! Yes, in some of the answers to questions that about other aspects (of either how to handle the input, or other list operations), the question is answered without a full clean up before exit. (recall, all allocated memory is freed on exit anyway) So if the code just exits (instead of returning back to some other part of the program), you can let program exit handle the free -- there is no risk of a memory leak at that point. However, since you are doing things properly, you would want to delete (free) the list before exit. Sharp eyes jian!

Answer (score 0):

in `add_patients` the following happens

Create Node

```
/* Create a temporary node */
temp = (patient_t*) malloc(sizeof(patient_t));
```

Fill Node with what ever Data

```
/* Copy Data to temporary Node */
printf("Enter Patient ID: ");
..
..
temp->nextp = NULL;
```

The linked list alterations

```
if(patient_headp == NULL){
    patient_headp = temp;
}
else{
    patient_currentp = patient_headp;
    while(patient_currentp->nextp != NULL){
        patient_currentp = patient_currentp->nextp;
    }
    patient_currentp->nextp = temp;
}
```

at this point `temp` is still pointing to the allocated memory so does `linked list`

and then this

```
free(temp);
```

results in `segfault`. so remove the `free`

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I am able to add patients and save that to my database. However, when I open the program up again, load the patient info, it loads and prints to the terminal. When I try to use the view patient option, I just get a segmentation fault 11.

Comment: patient_currentp = patient_headp; is that what you really want to do here, also check if you need a double pointer instead of single pointer. essentially in read_patients your patient_headp is not getting filled correctly.